# Android Studio trying to make spread chain style in constraint layout how?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have 3 images view like below in my xml file and trying to make them chain spread but didn't succeed.
I try to select the layout then select right click -> Chains -> horizontal chain layout but this option is turned off.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivSupprimer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivEntreprises"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivSupprimer"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivEteindre"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivEntreprises"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am following this solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a ConstraintLayout Chain, all involved widgets must be bi-directionally chained together.

If you have

```
| <- 1 -> <- 2 -> <- 3 ->|
```

Horizontally speaking (as this *example* is of a horizontal chain):

- 1 is the *head* of the chain (where you put the chain type).
- 1 is pinned START to PARENT, and *END to START of 2*.
- 2 is pinned START to END of 1, and END to START of 3.
- 3 is pinned START to END of 2, and END to PARENT.

In your XML, the 1st view of your chain (its head) is *not pinned* to the start of its second sibling:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivSupprimer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />
```

You'd need to add `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/ivEntreprises"`

The same goes for the other(s) in the chain. Always pin start/end together, like a well... *chain*.

Also, you *must not* use the `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"` (or any chain style) on widgets that are *NOT THE HEAD OF THE CHAIN*. This is only needed Once per chain.

Rules:

1. A widget can only be the HEAD of ONE chain per direction, meaning it can be the head of a vertical, and horizontal chain, but not the head of multiple horizontal chains (note, I don't know how you'd do this, and I haven't really tried to break this rule, but I'd assume it wouldn't work).
2. The declaration of a chain must only be preset in the HEAD of the chain.
3. The HEAD of the chain is the *leftmost* item in a horizontal chain, and the *topmost* item in a vertical chain.
4. Chains must pin to the edges (parent) on start/end (horizontal chains) and top/bottom (vertical chains), and have each widget pinned to each other, forming a virtual *chain* of widgets.

Find more information about chains in [this documentation](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html) or [the android official constraint layout chains documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/constraint-layout#constrain-chain).

Answer (score 1):

Select the 3 items you want in the chain then right click.

The chains menu will be available.
Select  "chains" -> "Create Horizontal Chain"
After that selecting any member of the chain will allow you to access the
Chains->"Horizontal Chain Style" menu.

Tip: It is easier to multi-select on the "Component Tree" on the left.